# Java Class Not Found Exception When Trying to Connect Into Database

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Im trying to insert data into SQL SERVER 2008 database through java class. Here is my code:

```
        public class DB_Sample
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                String dbUrl = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://ZAFRAN-PC:1433;databaseName=presentasi;integratedSecurity=true";

                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();;
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl); 
                Statement st =  con.createStatement();

                st.executeUpdate("Insert into barang(nama_barang, jumlah_stok, merk, harga_barang) values('HANDUK','30','ADIDAS','25000')");
                con.commit();

                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from barang");
                String i1="";

                while(rs.next())
                {
                i1 = rs.getString(1);

                System.out.println("Nama barang: " +i1+ " Berhasil Diinputkan");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
    }
```

Also i add sqljdbc4.jar in CLASSPATH.

```
.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;
```

But when i run my java class  throug CMD i got an error message like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

So whats the problem i have ? and how i can fix this problem ?

Comment: Hope you have jar file in path location ?

Comment: Hemanth: Sure, i have jar file in path location too

Comment: May I know how classpath was updated ?

Comment: @Hemanth: I Set my classpath through System Properties -> Environment Variable->Classpath

Comment: Add ;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\ to Path environment variable. It will work

Comment: @Hemanth: I was added  ;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\ to PATH environment variable. But it doesn't work

Comment: Please remove slash after enu and try

Comment: @Hemanth: i dont know what the problem here, i was tried your suggestion but its still doesnt work

Comment: The Path you mentioned in your comment `C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\`  , added manually(By Writing) or Copy-Paste from address bar. Do one thing put you jar inside a folder like `C:\driver\sqljdbc_4.0.jar` and add this classpath also which Java version you are using?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: I as put .jar inside a folder and add it into classpath. but its still doesnt work
i use java version: 1.8.0_31

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: subodh can you tell me step by step how to add sqljdbc_auth.dll in java.library.path?

Comment: `sqljdbc_auth.dll` ? or jar `sqljdbc_4.0.jarl` file? Also i will suggest run same program from IDE like eclipse only this add same jar file into Java Build Path and tell me what you are getting?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: i add sqljdbc_auth.dll in java library path. And i run this program from eclipse. of course i add sqlserver driver inside my eclipse project library. and it work !

Comment: good you are able to resolve the issue.